# are the rephrased sentences deemed correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, vocabulary, inversion

Extracted from Oxford Dictionary:

A. There is no way we could afford that sort of money.

B. No way am I going to drive them there

and

C. No way could we afford that sort of money.

D. There is no way I am going to drive them there.

E. No way is there I am going to drive them there.

F. In no way I am going to drive them there.

---

I am wondering:

- if all the items- C, D, E, and F - are considered correct, grammatically and semantically and
- ***if A,B,C,D,E and F mean the same thing***:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E is not grammatically correct.  What follows *is there* has to be a noun or noun phrase.

A and C mean the same.

B, D, and F mean the same.